# Converting JDBC Result Set to Nested Array List

Tags: java, jdbc

Using JDBC, I have managed to run a query on a database and receive a result set (rs). Using this information, I hope to generate a nested array list.

```
// Created Array List
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<SessionRecord>> tempSessionOrg = new ArrayList<ArrayList<SessionRecord>>();
```

The inner list needs to be grouped by the information returned from the first column. And this is all I've got thus far:

```
while(rs.next()) { 
          SessionRecord temp = new SessionRecord(rs.getString("SessionID"),rs.getString("NetworkAddress"),rs.getString("EventType"),rs.getString("Time"),rs.getString("Name"),rs.getString("SessionType"),rs.getString("ProcessType")); 
      }
```

I've already written a very similar program, with the exception that it places the result set into a single ArrayList without nesting. Unfortunatley, this analagous piece of code hasn't really helped me come up with a solution.

```
while(rs.next()) {
    dbSession.add(new SessionRecord(rs.getString("name"),rs.getString("ParticipantName"),rs.getString("GuestLoggedOnUsername"),rs.getString("GuestMachineName"),rs.getString("inicio"),rs.getString("diferencia")));
}
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

At this point, I have the following two blocks one code.

One:

```
public static ArrayList<SessionRecord> singleSessionRecords = new ArrayList<SessionRecord>();
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<SessionRecord>> tempSessionOrg = new ArrayList<ArrayList<SessionRecord>>();
```

Two:

```
while(rs.next()) { 
          singleSessionRecords.add(new SessionRecord(rs.getString("SessionID"),rs.getString("NetworkAddress"),rs.getString("EventType"),rs.getString("Time"),rs.getString("Name"),rs.getString("SessionType"),rs.getString("ProcessType"))); 
      }

      Map<String, List<SessionRecord>> byID = singleSessionRecords.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SessionRecord::SessionID));
      tempSessionOrg.add((ArrayList<SessionRecord>) Map.values());
```

I'm receiving a type mismatch error for the Map line and that I can't make a static reference to a non-static method in the final line. The later of the two is easy enough of a fix for me, but I'm not sure how to implement the Map properly.

Comment: Use a `Map<String, List<SessionRecord>>` where the key is the first column value, and the value is a list of all the records having this first column values. Once the map is created, creating a List<List<SessionRecord>> is a piece of cake: `new ArrayList<>(map.values())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Java 8?
If so this could easily be achieved by this code :

```
Map<String, List<SessionRecord>> byName
         = temp.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SessionRecord::name));
```

In this example I'm grouping the sessionRecords by name, you can easily change this to fit your grouping needs.

Comment: When I modify your example to group by SessionID (literally only changing "name" to "SessionID" in this case), I get a type mismatch error. It says it can't convert Map<Object,List<SessionRecord>> to Map<String,List<SessionRecord>>. Do you have any suggestions on how to correct my statement?

Comment: What type is SessionID?
Change the map to suite that type for example: 
Map<SessionID, List<SessionRecord>> OR
Map<?, List<SessionRecord>>

Comment: SessionID is a String

Comment: Well, its probably not.
Check if the line
String x = sessionRecord.sessionId;
complies.

You probably declared sessionId as an object.